# Separate items by dictionary or list

Tags: c#

I'm developing a game server for a game client. The game's character has an inventory, like any other game. The inventory has 4 tabs:

Equipment, Potions, Extra, Cash

Currently, the `CharacterItems` class is a `List<Item>`, where each `Item` object contains a `Slot` property which indicates the position of the item inside the window (the window is 4 by 4).

I don't really like this approach as it doesn't really indicate where each item is located, where with a dictionary I can have keys for each tab and then organize the item. However, I also need to index the items with a slot. So how can I use this approach with a dictionary? Wouldn't I need two dictionaries like so? `Dictionary<InventoryTab, Dicitionary<int, Item>>`, where `InventoryTab` is a certain tab and the keyed collection is indexed by the item's slot? Seems too cluttered, perhaps there is a better appraoch for this?

Also, the character also has wearable equipment on it. So that means I have to create another definition in the dictionary for equipped tab, which kinda ruins the logic.

Here's a test for the apparoach I mentioned before:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace InventoryTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var inventory = new Inventory();

            while (true)
            {
                var mapleId = new Random().Next(1000000, 5999999);

                short str = 0;
                short dex = 0;
                short intt = 0;
                short luk = 0;

                if (mapleId >= 1000000 && mapleId <= 1999999)
                {
                    str = (short)new Random().Next(0, 5);
                    dex = (short)new Random().Next(0, 5);
                    intt = (short)new Random().Next(0, 5);
                    luk = (short)new Random().Next(0, 5);
                }

                var item = new Item()
                {
                    MapleId = mapleId,
                    Str = str,
                    Dex = dex,
                    Int = intt,
                    Luk = luk
                };

                inventory.Add(item);

                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }

    class Item
    {
        public int MapleId { get; set; }
        public short Str { get; set; }
        public short Dex { get; set; }
        public short Int { get; set; }
        public short Luk { get; set; }

        public Tab Tab
        {
            get
            {
                return (Tab)(this.MapleId / 1000000);
            }
        }
    }

    enum Tab : byte
    {
        Equip = 1,
        Use,
        Setup,
        Etc,
        Cash
    }

    class Inventory : Dictionary<Tab, Dictionary<sbyte, Item>>
    {
        public Inventory()
        : base()
        {
            foreach (var tab in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Tab)).Cast<Tab>())
            {
                base.Add(tab, new Dictionary<sbyte, Item>(96));
            }
        }

        public void Add(Item item)
        {
            var nextFreeSlot = this.GetNextFreeSlot(item.Tab);

            this[item.Tab].Add(nextFreeSlot, item);

            Console.WriteLine("Added new item to {0} tab. Info:", item.Tab);
            Console.WriteLine("Slot: {0}", nextFreeSlot);
            Console.WriteLine("MapleId: {0}", item.MapleId);

            if (item.Str > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Str: {0}", item.Str);
            }
            if (item.Dex > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Dex: {0}", item.Dex);
            }
            if (item.Int > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Int: {0}", item.Int);
            }
            if (item.Luk > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Luk: {0}", item.Luk);
            }
        }

        private sbyte GetNextFreeSlot(Tab tab)
        {
            sbyte slot = 0;

            foreach (var item in this[tab])
            {
                if (item.Key == slot)
                {
                    slot += 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            return slot;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You do know that calling `new Random().Next(1000000, 5999999)` in a tight loop will not give you random numbers? You should always only ever instantiate one instance of `Random` (at least per thread) in your app. Oh, and `new Random().Next(0, 5)` too. They'll all be the same number most likely.

Comment: First of all don't inherit from `Dictionary` if you don't want to create a class which is intended to be used as dictionary elsewhere, use it as member. Also it's not clear, why you are using special types like `byte`, `sbyte` and `short` instead of the default integer numeric type.

Comment: @abto Because the packet contains those values as those data types.

Comment: @GilbertWilliams - Is there a reason you only want numbers in the range of 1,000,000 to 5,999,998? Do you now also want 5,999,999?